# Simplify series of powers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there any closed form for the following series?

$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\,\frac{1}{m!(m+1)!}\,(-\alpha^2)^m\,\, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\,\frac{(m+n)!}{n!(n+1)!}\,(-\beta^2)^n$$

I only know that the overall series is convergent.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that last exponent an $n$ rather than an $m$?

Comment: @RonGordon thanks!

Comment: May I ask how you came across this series? It is always nice to have a little context, if possible.

Comment: @julien Expressing the bessel fuctions as series in the following integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\,J_1(ak)J_1(bk)k^{-1}\exp(-ck^2)\,\,dk$$ and calculating the odd moments of the gaussian function!

Comment: That would have made a nice introduction to your question! Maybe you could add that. Do you mean you hope for a closed form for $J_1(ak)J_2(bk)$? In this case I don't see where the $(m+n)!$ comes from. Or is it something else?

Comment: @julien $$J_1(ak)J_1(bk)k^{-1}\propto k^{2n+2m+1}$$ and $$\int_0^{\infty}\,k^{2(n+m)+1}\,\exp(-ak^2)\,dk=\frac{(m+n)!}{2a^{m+n+1}}$$ from [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html).